c++ - llvm assignments
I am a LLVM newbie.
I am trying to replace instructions this way: 
b=a*1 -> b=a 
here is a snippet of the pass i wrote
    SmallVector<llvm::Instruction*> del;
    for(auto Iter=B.begin(); Iter!=B.end();Iter++){
        Instruction &instr=*Iter;
        int nOp=1;
        outs() << "\t" << instr.getOpcodeName() << "\n";
        if(instr.getOpcodeName()=="mul"){
            for(auto *IterI= instr.op_begin(); IterI!=instr.op_end();IterI++){
                Value *operand= *IterI;
                if(ConstantInt *C = dyn_cast <ConstantInt>(operand)){
                    outs() <<nOp<< "\n";
                    APInt i=C->getValue();
                    if(i.isOne()){
                        Type* inType= operand->getType();
                        AllocaInst *alloc= new AllocaInst(inType, NULL,instr.getOperand(nOp),Twine(*"hw"), &instr);
                        StoreInst *s=new StoreInst(instr.getOperand(nOp),alloc,&instr);
                        LoadInst *l=new LoadInst(inType,alloc,Twine(*"v"),&instr);
                        instr.replaceAllUsesWith(l);
                        del.push_back(&instr);
                    }

nOp is used to define which operator of the instruction should be used for assignments.
Mul are replaced but is this the right way to do an assignment?

It's not a bad way. I'd do it a bit simpler, using is_a<>() to identify the instruction instead of the opcode name, and do if if(mul->getOperand(1) …) mul->replaceAllUsesWith(mul->getOperand(0); … else if(mul->getOperand(0) … mul->replaceAllUsesWith(mul->getOperand(1); etc. to make it work after mem2reg. A DCE pass afterwards cleans up the unnecessary instructions.
